# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types'

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, setuptools, virtualenvwrapper, netscape

I am creating a virtual environment using `mkvirtualenv`, and I get this error, where have I gone wrong?

```
$ mkvirtualenv data
New python executable in /home/usman/.virtualenvs/data/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/usman/.virtualenvs/data/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 386, in find_all_candidates
    self.find_links, expand_dir=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 236, in _sort_locations
    sort_path(os.path.join(path, item))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 217, in sort_path
    if mimetypes.guess_type(url, strict=False)[0] == 'text/html':
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py", line 293, in guess_type
    init()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py", line 358, in init
    db.read(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py", line 202, in read
    with open(filename) as fp:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types'
```

Comment: try with `sudo`

Comment: What gives `ls -l /usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types`?

Comment: @phd It gives `-rw------- 1 root root 106 ago 14 23:52 /usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types
```

Comment: Thanks. This error arose for me after some updates and/or reinstalling citrix (icaclient). Any idea what specifically might have caused this (reset permissions of this file) ?

Comment: @jessexknight Copying/installing file(s) with wrong permissions and/or wrong `umask`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your file "mime.types" has not the sufficient permission status.
Use the chmod command as mentioned earlier.